# Visual Studio 2015でAndroid署名付きリリースビルドをするには？

Tags: android, onsen-ui, visual-studio

Windows7でVisual Studio Community 2015を使って開発しています。
Onsen-UIを利用したハイブリッドアプリです。
Androidのデバッグビルドと署名なしのリリースビルドはできましたが、
署名ありのリリースビルドの方法がわかりません。
別のツールを使わず、可能ならVisual Studioだけで行いたいです。

> Android の署名を構成するには、http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613579 の手順に従ってください

と表示されるので上記URLを見に行きましたが、該当する説明と違ってres\native\androidが存在しないのでどうも分かりません。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: OnsenUIのタグが付いていたのでハイブリッドアプリなのでしょうか。Visual Studioには詳しくないのですが、そのあたりのことを明記すると回答が得やすいかもしれません。